# Why are there two matches with .* regex?

Tags: regex, powershell

Why does the following generate two matches and therefore `"xx"` as the output:

```
"Hello" -Replace '.*','x'
```

Whereas this just generates one match and therefore just `"x"` in the output:

```
"Hello" -Replace '^.*','x'
```

I'm trying to understand what nuance of regex cause two matches in the first?

You can put the same into https://regex101.com and it also reports two matches with the first match being `"Hello"` and the second match being `""`

Answer (score 6):

That's because the `*` quantifier matches **zero** or more characters. In that case, it matches the entire word, `Hello`, then an empty string after it.

Use `.+`, and it will match at least one character instead.

When you use the `^.*`, which looks at the beginning of the string, it only has one match, because it can't match an empty string there, as there is an `H` character in the starting.

Comment: You could also anchor it, `^.*`

Comment: Or you can simply take out the `g` flag